# Djoser: trigger action on user account activation

Tags: django, account, activation, djoser

I have djoser integrated on my django project, and I need to create a stripe customer_id on account activation, how can I do this?

I've been searching on djoser doc, but there is nothing about customizing activation, or passing a callback method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Djoser provides [user_activated](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/bb2f3dc066f912c764c5d1194a09ded47bbb394c/djoser/signals.py#L8) signal. It is usable just like ordinary django signal.
It's undocumented but working.

#### Example usage

```
from django.dispatch import receiver

from djoser.signals import user_activated

@receiver(user_activated)
def my_handler(user, request):
    # do what you need here
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I see that this code has been since 2015 on master, could be deprecated or just they forgot to document it?

Comment: It's just not documented. The code works and is covered by tests. I will add documentation.

Comment: Just for curiosity, are you a developer of the project?